# What portion of an Instrument Proficiency Check must be in the airplane?

Tags: faa-regulations, flight-training, instrument-flight-rules

I was asked this question by the Chief Instructor at my Part 141 school. I've looked all over and I can't seem to find an answer to this question. We often use the AATD which is a Redbird full motion but I've not heard anything about a specific portion being in the airplane whether or not you did it all in a sim, or a mixture of simulator and airplane. Can anyone elaborate on this? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is explained in the [Instrument Rating ACS](https://www.faa.gov/training_testing/testing/acs/media/instrument_rating_acs.pdf) (page A-18):

> ***Instrument Proficiency Check***
>
> If a person fails to meet the experience requirements of section 61.57(c), a pilot may only
>   establish instrument currency through an instrument proficiency check
>   as described in section 61.57(d). An FSTD may be used as part of an
>   approved curriculum to accomplish all or portions of this check. If
>   specified in its LOA, an AATD may be used to complete most of the
>   required Tasks. However, the circling approach, the landing Task, and
>   the multiengine airplane Tasks must be accomplished in an aircraft or
>   FFS (Level B, C, or D).A BATD cannot be used for an instrument
>   proficiency check. Please see the Task Table in Appendix 5 for
>   additional information. (Appendix 5, Instrument Proficiency Check
>   Table).

To summarize:

- If the simulator is an approved FFS, you can do the whole IPC in it
- If the simulator is an approved AATD, you can do everything except circling, landing and multi-engine tasks
- Otherwise, you need to use an aircraft

Comment: Specific info available at the [Redbird website](https://landing.redbirdflight.com/posts/heres-what-you-need-to-know-about-the-new-aviation-training-device-rules)